# Conversão Farenheit Celsius

Tags: c++

Fazer um algoritmo que calcule e escreva uma tabela de centígrados em função de graus
Farenheit, que variam de 50 a 150 de 1 em 1
Eu encontrei a solução em C não em C++,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for (float F = 50; F < 150; F++) {
        float Ce;
        Ce = (5 / 9) * (F - 32);
        cout << "\nFarenheit " << F << "\nCentigrados  " << Ce;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (float F = 50; F > 150; F++)`, por que `F > 150`?

Comment: è pra fazer uma sequencia

Comment: Exatamente, mas por que colocou no `for` `F > 150`? Você sabe como funciona o `for` e o que é cada parâmetro?

Comment: Repetir até que F seja maior que 150

Comment: O for eu sei pouco

Comment: A sintaxe do `for` deve ser lida como "repetir **enquanto**"

Comment: Então  o certo é F<150

Comment: deu certo essa parte, o problema agora é o centigrados

Comment: Farenheit 50
Centigrados  0
Farenheit 51
Centigrados  0
Farenheit 52
Centigrados  0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao fazer a divisão de um inteiro por um inteiro o resultado será, também, um inteiro. Ou seja, se você dividir 5 por 9, sendo ambos inteiros, terá como resultado 0, pois é a parte inteira do resultado real. Desta forma, independente do valor de `F`, você sempre multiplicará por zero, o que justifica a sua saída ser sempre zero.

Se você precisa de uma divisão real, utilize pelo menos um dos operandos como sendo real.

```
C = (5.0/9)*(F-32)
```

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito